# Bring Header/Footer (Images) in front of body in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, headers, pictures

In Microsoft Word, I have an `In Line with Text` picture in my document body. (below)

[image: 01]

Then a picture inserted in the Header as `In Font of Text`. (below)

[image: 02]

I want to set the this picture (in Header) being in front of the body picture. (below)

[image: 03]

Regards.

Comment: You could increase the height of the header such that your entire header image is visible or set the text wrapping of the header image to "Top and Bottom. "

Comment: This cannot be done. The body of the document will ALWAYS be in front of the header/footer layer. What could be done would be to copy the image from the header and paste it in the same location in the body. *(This will need to be monitored when you edit text before that image anywhere in the document because it will be anchored to a paragraph in the body.)*

Answer (score 1):

Based on the research I've done, the header and footer are in a layer under the main document.  There doesn't appear to be any way to put any object in the header/footer above main document text.

One possible solution is to create a unique header (e.g. "Different first page" or "Different Odd & Even Pages") or using a section break and place the large image in the header or footer.  It's not an elegant solution, but it may work.